# How to gain a lost connection to server without restarting the Server, when a listener thread dies

Tags: multithreading, spring, threadpool, rabbitmq

I am trying to listen to RabbitMQ queue by polling it. But somehow due to network issues if once connection to queue is lost then thread silently dies off and connection and everything is closed. But this is a background task and we wont know untill queue really grows huge and start send out notification.

Can some one please help me with graceful shutdown of thread (which I guess I am already doing by dealing carefully with exception in catch clause). But I don't know how to re-start a stopped thread.

Is there a way through which I can restart a new instance of stopped thread.

PS: I am instantiating the thread using @postconstruct and calling init thread soon after container loads all beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to me that you are not doing proper exception handling.  You say "thread silently dies off" but that doesn't happen in Java.  I would audit your exceptions and watch for the following problems:

- Watch out for `throws Exception` on a method.  This hides all sorts of evils.  A method should usually enumerate the exceptions that it throws.
- If an Exception throws too many different types of exceptions then that is a signal that it is too large.  Consider splitting it into multiple smaller methods.  Or handle the specific exceptions inside of the method and throw one exception out.
- Try to have small try/catch blocks which catch a single exception if possible.  Don't inclose huge blocks of code with `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }`.  That, again, hides evils.
- If you catch an exception, make sure you aren't just blindly continuing.  If this is a background thread then maybe it should exit or restart the socket or...
- Make sure you are properly reporting *all* exceptions.  Every catch block should do something with the exception.  `e.printStackTrace()` may work but providing more information about the problem is usually in order.

> But I don't know how to re-start a stopped thread.

You do not re-start a stopped thread, you start another one.  If the thread should not be shutting down at all then it needs to re-open a socket or maybe re-start its `RabbitMQ` connection.  Again, it's about proper exception handling.  I don't know `RabbitMQ` but something like the following pseudo code might help:

```
public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
       Connection conn = null;
       try {
           conn = rabbitMq.start();
           processQueue(conn);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO: log the exception here
       } finally {
           // make sure we close the connection
           if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
       }
       try {
          // we sleep here to not spin if the RabbitMQ host goes down
          Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
          // bail if someone interrupts us
          return;
       }
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gray.. I could resolve the problem now . I was in impression that as soon as thread gets an exception it goes to catch block and then the thread is claimed by JVM. Which obviously not the case as per your answer.

Comment: what I have understood from your answer is "even if exception occurs then also the thread is alive (provided exception is handled properly), and it will keep trying to get back connection, once it gets the connection it will do its normal things"

.....Kindly confirm my understanding is correct

Comment: Yes, exactly right @Anupam.  Exception handling does not mean that anything is killed.  Only if the end of the `run()` method is reached does the thread go away -- it is never silently.  Remember also that the main thread is the same way.

Comment: just one last thing rather addition to your above comment... "Only if the end of the run() method is reached does the thread go away" also if exception is not handled properly then exception keep going down the stack until it hit rock bottom i.e. JVM and hence sudden death..

Comment: Sure but that happens at the end of the `run()` method.  And that would only happen if it is a `RuntimeException` sine otherwise it would have had to been caught.

Answer (score 2):

If you are properly ("gracefully") handling the exception then your connection will be retrieved by thread .. just put it in while true loop and keep listening to queue ..Once network connection (and eventually queue connection) will be alive then your thread will get the connection.

Comment: your answer seems correct to me.. But Grays answer is more elaborate and easy to understand.